# How can I use condition on the meteor template?

Tags: meteor

I want to use a  condition on the meteor template like:
for example I have a field it name is type ,type can get two values 1 and 2

I  try like below but it doesnt work.

```
    {{#if type 1}}
    <td tableHeadData='day'> {{day}}</td>
    {{else type 2}}
    <td tableHeadData='month'> {{month}}</td>
    {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package in meteor named `raix:handlebar-helpers` that have some simple helpers.

So if you want to use equal then you just have to write `{{#if $eq a b}}`.

```
{{#if $eq type 1}}
    <td tableHeadData='day'> {{day}}</td>
  {{else}} 
      {{#if $eq type 2}}
         <td tableHeadData='month'> {{month}}</td>
      {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

You can also write your helper locally and globally.

For locally you have write in the corresponding js file helpers.

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    isEqual : function (value1, value2){
       return value1 === value2;
    }
})
```

For globally you have to register a helper using Template.registerHelper.

```
Template.registerHelper('isEqual', function (value1, value2) {
  return value1 === value2;
});
```

In the both type of helper you html code will like

```
{{#if isEqual type 1}}
    <td tableHeadData='day'> {{day}}</td>
  {{else}} 
      {{#if isEqual type 2}}
         <td tableHeadData='month'> {{month}}</td>
      {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

*@note : meteor spacebar does not support any else if condition for now.*

Answer (score 1):

You can make an `equals` helper for re-usability

```
Template.registerHelper('equals', function (a, b) {
  return a == b; // maybe triple equals of types need to match
});
```

Then use in template like this:

```
{{#if equals value1 value2}}
  Your values are equal
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can't. The argument to `if` has to be a Template helper function that returns a boolean. So you will have to write a helper function that does the test.

```
Template.xxx.helpers({
  typeIs1() { return this.type === 1 }
  typeIs2() { return this.type === 2 }
})
```